# Really slow converting host vars to env file with ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following task in ansible:

```
- name: Set env vars
  lineinfile:
    path: "~/.env"
    mode: 0600
    create: yes
    line: "{{ item.key|upper }}=\"{{ item.value }}\""
    regexp: "^{{ item.key|upper }}="
  loop: "{{ env_file |dict2items }}"
```

It's creating the `.env` file line-by-line but it is REALLY slow. Is there a better way?

The .yml file looks like:

```
env_file:
  key1: "value1"
  key2: "value2"
```

The resulting file has the format:

```
KEY1="value1"
KEY2="value2"
```

Each line takes about 20 seconds to process and it really adds up.

Comment: Very probably there is something wrong with the connection. To be sure, try the same task locally (- hosts: localhost).

Comment: @VladimirBotka I'm inclined to agree, or it was some sort of memory leak because I restarted my IDE and the whole process sped up considerably. Still, A. Darwin's solution is good and I'm using it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `template` module and writing a Jinja2 file. It tends to be faster than `lineinfile` when dealing with loops.

Comment: Thank you, for the benefit of others the jinja2 file should look like this:
`
{% for k, v in env_file.items() %}
{{ k | upper }}="{{ v }}"
{% endfor %}
` (add appropriate linebreaks)